# Recycler View Performance when using SpannedString

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, spanned

I'm using SpannedString for coloring some specials character in textView. When I'm not using SpannedString and just set plain text, everything works fine, But when I use SpannedString, scrolling is very slow and is very laggy.

I know that onBindViewHolder function should be very simple but I tried different ways to store spanned String and also used htmlString, but got no improvements.
I also use regex to find special characters, but in LG devices, the previous character is colored too and I have to force other characters' color to be black.

I also test setHasFixedSize, setExtraLayoutSpace, and constraint-layout; but it doesn't change.

Here is my onBindViewHolder function:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AyeViewHolder holder, int i) {

    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    SpannedString result = new SpannedString("");
    for (int j = 0; j < ayeList.get(i).getAye().length(); j++) {
        SpannableStringBuilder wordtoSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder(ayeList.get(i).getAye().substring(j,j+1));

        if (arabicV.contains(ayeList.get(i).getAye().substring(j, j + 1))) {
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(context,
                    PrefUtils.ARABIC_COLOR, "#FF0000"))),
                    0, 1 , 0);

        }else if (endSuffix.contains(ayeList.get(i).getAye().substring(j, j + 1))) {
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor( "#00acc2")),
                    0, 1 , 0);
        }else {
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#000000")),
                    0, 1, 0);
        }
        result = (SpannedString) TextUtils.concat(result,"",wordtoSpan);
    }
    holder.aye.setText(result, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

[here is a screenshot from my recylcerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNaCu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to out a loop with the search for symbols for highlighting from the onBindViewHolder method and transfer it to the model. You need to calculate all the intervals in the some place - before output in adater. And then in the method onBindViewHolder just use them.

**In your model**

```
public class Aye {
    private String aye;
    private ArrayList<SpannableStringBuilder> spans;

    public Aye(String aye, String arabicV, String endSuffix) {
        this.aye = aye;
        this.spans = getSearchSpans(aye, arabicV, endSuffix);
    }

    public String getAye() {
        return aye;
    }

    public ArrayList<SpannableStringBuilder> getSpans() {
        return spans;
    }

    private ArrayList<SpannableStringBuilder> getSearchSpans(String aye, String arabicV, String endSuffix) {
        ArrayList<SpannableStringBuilder> spans = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < aye.length(); j++) {
            SpannableStringBuilder wordToSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder(aye.substring(j, j + 1));

            if (arabicV.contains(aye.substring(j, j + 1))) {
                wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(context, PrefUtils.ARABIC_COLOR, "#FF0000"))), 0, 1, 0);

            } else if (endSuffix.contains(aye.substring(j, j + 1))) {
                wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#00acc2")), 0, 1, 0);
            } else {
                wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#000000")), 0, 1, 0);
            }

            SpannedString result = (SpannedString) TextUtils.concat(result, "", wordToSpan);
            spans.add(wordToSpan);
        }
        return spans;
    }
}
```

**in your adapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AyeViewHolder holder, int i) {

    String aye = ayeList.get(i).getAye();
    ArrayList<SpannableStringBuilder> ayeSpans = ayeList.get(i). getSpans();

    for (SpannableStringBuilder span : ayeSpans) {
        holder.aye.setText(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must relax the loop by taking out as many statements, assignments as you can, 
like before the loop declare these:

```
    ForegroundColorSpan colorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(context, PrefUtils.ARABIC_COLOR, "#FF0000")));
    ForegroundColorSpan colorSpanEnd = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor( "#00acc2"));
    ForegroundColorSpan colorSpan0 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor( "#000000"));
```

and inside the loop:

```
String sub = ayeList.get(i).getAye().substring(j,j+1);
```

and then:

```
        if (arabicV.contains(sub)) {
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(colorSpan,0, 1 , 0);

        }else if (endSuffix.contains(sub)) {
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(colorSpanEnd,0, 1 , 0);
        }else {
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(colorSpan0,0, 1, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

You may be experiencing performance issues because of this line because each item in the RecyclerView will create a new ViewHolder instead of recycling existing ones. You can remove this line after following above answers.